# How safe is it to run fsck on faulty HDD?

Tags: 16.04, filesystem, fsck

Our system recently stopped working--we can still SSH, but most programs on our server result in an Input/Output error, so we can't SSH out of the server, open FTP to it, etc.

I have a MySQL database I absolutely must not lose--I can see the files in `/var/lib/mysql` just fine, but I have absolutely no way to get them out of the system. The drive `/dev/sda4` on `/` with type `ext4` is the bad one--as I understand it, I need to run `fsck`, but these prompts scare me quite a bit.

If I see the files in `/var/lib/mysql`, it means they're okay, and there's no way fsck will delete them if part of them are damaged? I can just run `fsck -y` and stay calm? My provider told me that I need to shutdown the system to connect the new HDD to move my stuff to it, but I am incapable of rebooting without repairing the drive.

Can I run `fsck -y` without worrying?

Comment: I would probably not risk it. Don't you have any way to back up your files first? *Normally* `fsck` should not do more harm than good, but who knows what happens on a corrupted file system...

Comment: the best thing to do if you have an external drive, clone the faulty drive to the external, the attempt repair/recovery on the external.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know of any way to back them up. I am incapable of SSHing; incapable of using SFTP; incapable of using PSCP; incapable of generating so much as a gzip. The only writable place I found is /dev. No other hard drives available; provider demanding to shut off the server in order to connect the hard drive.

Comment: http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php here is a bootable drive clone similar to norton ghost. any the server will have to be shut down in order to replace the fautly drive. and do repairs. even fsck should be done on an unmounted partition

Comment: I have only one drive and it's the one that's being a problem. I have nothing to clone it to. For the record, a specific partition is the problem, though it's basically the partition with everything in it.

Comment: with modern SMART technology, if the drive is showing errors it likely needs replacing.

Comment: I don't use sql but read there is a `dump` command to extract all the data from tables. This is used in backing up I read. Have you tried to backup your database? How large is your database? Will it fit on a USB thumb drive?

Comment: Yes, the drive needs replacing, but I mean, I am physically incapable of clong it right now. The provider wants to turn off the system, but I can't even do that, I first need to repair the system. I am VERY hesitant about asking the provider to just unplug the server, as I am very concerned that if it is shut down now, it will not be bootable again. The provider wants to shut down the server to plug the new drive so that I can properly migrate my data, but the short of it is that I need to run fsck and have been in limbo for hours now.

Comment: WinEunuuchs2Unix: The server is on a datacenter in a different continent. I am incapable of executing most programs on the server--mysql, mysqldump, even fdisk, nothing is working due to input/output errors. And I cannot write to anywhere on the system except /dev and /run as it's in read-only mode.

Comment: What makes you think you need to run `fsck`? I/O errors almost certainly mean the drive is physically damaged; `fsck` won't help with that. I think your files are lost, period.

Comment: Have you considered unplugging/shutting down, booting from another drive into a separate os, and cloning from there? I don't know if your service provider will have an Ubuntu drive just lying around, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, yes `fsck` is safe <sup>[1]</sup> (with caveats <sup>[2]</sup>) to run on a faulty disk/partition **if you unmount** the disk/partition **before**.

It's also possible to run `fsck` having just one drive/partition, if you enter into the *Runlevel 1* mode (`init 1` command) before.

**However**, be aware that your SSH connection will **get down** at the moment  you run `init 1` because it will kill<sup>[3]</sup> all running services and daemons (SSH is one of them).

Second, about your need of a mysql backup, I would try the following steps:

1. Make a SSH-tunnel onto your existing SSH session <sup>[4]</sup>;
2. Run `mysqldump` remotely <sup>[5]</sup>;
3. Check the `*.sql` generated by mysqldump;
4. And call authorized service to replace the damaged drive.

References:

- <sup>[1]</sup> [How to run `fsck` to fix your filesystems *[in Portuguese]*](https://elias.praciano.com/2014/03/como-verificar-e-consertar-seu-sistema-de-arquivos-no-ubuntu/)
- [2] [How To Recover from File System Corruption Using Fsck and a Recovery ISO](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-recover-from-file-system-corruption-using-fsck-and-a-recovery-iso)
- [3] [Will “init 1” from a remote (via VPN) ssh session kill my ssh connection](https://serverfault.com/questions/96561/will-init-1-from-a-remote-via-vpn-ssh-session-kill-my-ssh-connection)
- [4] [Using an already established SSH channel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33557/using-an-already-established-ssh-channel)
- [5] [How to dump remote database without mysqldump?](https://serverfault.com/a/134024)

Best regards!

Comment: In the end, the MySQL database survived, thanks! Though, I was incapable of making and pulling a backup because the program mysqldump, and really most others, even base64, were giving Input/Output error.

Comment: Nice! I'm glad that your database is safe! Did you try  the mysqldump remotely via SSH as I described? I'm curious to know if in your critical case it works.